# Is there a Standard function to copy a cstring (possibly literal) into a std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

Is there any way to write a cstring literal (or variable) directly into an existing std::array?

I.e., I want to do something like this:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 100> test;
// std::copy("testing", test);
// test="testing";
```

I expect the behavior to be "copy until either a null terminator is copied or the destination buffer is full."

I was trying to avoid doing a strlcpy(test.data()... because I was looking for a way that could cope with a buffer overrun without having to explicitly include the buffer length as a parameter.

Thanks.

---

edit:

Here're the best solutions I've found so far from suggestions.  This one only works for literals. MSVC does not have uniform initialization, so it requires the = before then {. It also requires the buffer size, but fails compilation if the buffers sizes don't match or if there is an overrun:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::array<char, 100> arr1={"testing"};
   std::array<char, 100> arr2;
   arr2=arr1;
   std::cout << arr2.data();
}
```

This one works for strings in general, but be careful because the embedded null does not get copied and to have the null included you have to construct by array, ie string mystring("junk\0", 5).

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const std::string str("testing");
  std::array<char, 100> arr;
  std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), arr.begin());
  // Note that the null terminator does not get copied.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 100> test = { "testing" };
```

If you use a too-large string literal, the `std::array` construction will fail on compile time. This won't work for non-literals though.

For non-literals, you need to check for the null terminator yourself. You could do something like `std::copy(my_non_literal, my_non_literal + length_literal, test.begin());`, but I think you've already come across that one.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to avoid a constructor. ;)

Comment: @cwm9, It isn't one. `std::array` is an aggregate.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm trying to write into an existing memory location, not define a new one.

Comment: Do you actually need the double braces in this case? My reasoning is that `char str[] = "Hello";` works without any braces.

Comment: @cwm9, Oh, that's right. I don't think MSVC has uniform initialization down. It should still work with one for this one, though.

Comment: @cwm9 Visual Studio doesn't support initializer lists.

Comment: Don't use VC if you want to use C++11 xD.

Comment: @Rapptz, That isn't really an initializer list in the sense that `std::array` has no initializer constructor.

Comment: @mfontanini, [This](http://liveworkspace.org/code/7871d142a1e07a99aac0f04890e1bb97) is what I mean. It should work with one set of braces.

Comment: @chris correct. It still wouldn't compile in VS2012 but it does in [GCC](http://liveworkspace.org/code/21f0391f5b3eb996364d0f19aaae6723). Although as you said, the double braces are unnecessary.

Comment: @Rapptz, Weird, [so does this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/76dc18bdc6872e279c7d4026c0cdaa9e). I've never seen that before. I'm guessing it's actually part of uniform initialization in a form I haven't seen.

Comment: It's close enough to get me somewhere near where I want to be:  http://liveworkspace.org/code/71ab4c46230012d42ec51d351a3efd43

Comment: @cwm9 unnecessary copy call. http://liveworkspace.org/code/00cbdac9355c1d1b7685595bcf9b457b

Comment: Yes, thanks Rapptz.  I'm fairly new to using ::std.  Been a decade since I've programmed much.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string str("testing");
  std::array<char, 100> arr;
  std::copy(str.begin(), std.end(), arr.begin());
}
```

Comment: make a note of the lack of a trailing null though.  That's kind of... critical.

Answer (score 0):

Direct operation between C strings and C++ data structures is not a problem the Standard library typically deals with. `c_str()` and the `std::string` constructor are pretty much it. You will have to manually write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

int main(){

    std::array<char,100> buffer;
    char * text = "Sample text.";
    std::memcpy (buffer.data(),text,100);
    std::cout << buffer.data() << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're falling off `text` on `memcpy` :P

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid the explicit 100 in the memcpy in case the size changes later.

Comment: that's why you have const variables.